# Flip image or inverse not sure

Tags: opengl

I am placeing 3 images next to each other and its giving a mirror look,  cant tell with the  + or - sign but with the words rows you can tell see it here..

[image: theimage]

Here is the code i use

```
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                  glTexCoord2f(0/4 + xoff,0/4 + yoff);       glVertex2f( x1,game->camera.height-y1);
                  glTexCoord2f(1.0/4 + xoff,0/4 + yoff);    glVertex2f( x2,game->camera.height-y1 );
                  glTexCoord2f(1.0/4 + xoff,1.0/4 + yoff); glVertex2f( x2,game->camera.height-y2 );
                  glTexCoord2f(0/4 + xoff,1.0/4 + yoff);    glVertex2f( x1,game->camera.height-y2 );

                glEnd();
```

i belive its just the way i am mapping the coords?

Comment: Just switch your y coordinates, either on texture or vertex (not both).

Comment: yup that worked.  got to love an easy fix "D

Comment: add answer and ill credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch your y coordinates, either on texture or vertex (not both).